# Gameplay3d - 'float round(float) throw()' already has a body

Tags: gameplay3d

I'm following this wiki: https://github.com/blackberry/GamePlay/wiki/Visual-Studio-Setup
After opening 'gameplay.sln' in  'VS Express 2013 for Desktop', and hitting 'F7'

I'm getting over 100 error like this:

> error C2084:function 'float round(float) throw()' already has a body
>
> (base.h)

and few of:

> error C2264: 'round' : error in function definition or declaration; function not called
> (slider.cpp)

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

visual studio 2013 -> use 'next' branch

master soon as v2.0.0 is coming

[GamePlay3d Forum link](http://www.gameplay3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1804&p=5376&hilit=round&sid=380fdd6a66ad62ccff347c6d77c399f2#p5376)